# Laravel Object Loosing data on View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a Laravel application form my company. From the controller I'm passing an object collection to the view, and on the view the last object of the collection looses data.

Here is a var_dump of the object on the controller:

```
    "id" => 26820
    "description" => "RASTRILLO PLASTICO TRUPER"
    "amount" => 6.0
    "quantity" => 1.0
    "unit_price" => 6.0
    "subtotal" => 6.0
    "transaction_date" => "2017-08-09 00:00:00"
    "sales_tax_amount" => 0.0
    "reference_number" => "946"
    "name" => "RASTRILLO PLASTICO TRUPER  "
    "cost" => "4.06"
    "sp" => "6.15"
    "upc" => "7501206659915"
    "mu" => "UNIDAD"
```

And here is a dump on the view:

```
'id' => int 26820
'description' => string 'RASTRILLO PLASTICO TRUPER' (length=25)
'amount' => float 6
'quantity' => float 1
'unit_price' => float 6
'subtotal' => float 6
'transaction_date' => string '2017-08-09 00:00:00' (length=19)
'sales_tax_amount' => float 0
'reference_number' => string '946' (length=3)
'name' => string 'RASTRILLO PLASTICO TRUPER' (length=25)
'cost' => string '0' (length=1)
'sp' => null
'upc' => string '7501206659915' (length=13)  
'mu' => string 'U' (length=1)
```

What can be happening to the object in order to loose cost and sp on the view?

Code that fetches the data from the database:

```
$results = self::query()
        ->select([
            'sale_invoice_line.id',
            'sale_invoice_line.description',
            'sale_invoice_line.amount',
            'sale_invoice_line.quantity',
            'sale_invoice_line.unit_price',
            'sale_invoice.amount as subtotal',
            'sale_invoice.transaction_date',
            'sale_invoice.sales_tax_amount',
            'sale_invoice.reference_number',
            'products.name',
            'products.cost',
            'products.sp',
            'products.upc',
            'products.mu'
        ])
        ->join('sale_invoice', 'sale_invoice_line.invoice_id', '=', 'sale_invoice.id')
        ->leftJoin('products', 'sale_invoice_line.item_id', '=', 'products.upc')
        ->join('store', 'store.id', '=', 'sale_invoice.store_id')
        ->whereBetween('sale_invoice.transaction_date', [$start_date, $end_date]);

    if ($store_id){
        $results = $results->where('store.id', $store_id);
    }

    return $results;
```

Code that shows the data on the view:

```
@foreach($product_sales as $sold_product)
    <tr data-sale-line="{{ $sold_product->id }}">
        <td class="text-center">{{ $sold_product->reference_number }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $sold_product->upc }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $sold_product->name ? $sold_product->name : $sold_product->description }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $sold_product->quantity }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ ucfirst($sold_product->mu) }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $sold_product->cost ? number_format(($sold_product->cost / 1.015), 2) : 'N/D' }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format($sold_product->unit_price,2) }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $sold_product->cost ? number_format($sold_product->cost / 1.015 * $sold_product->quantity,2) : 'N/D' }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format($sold_product->amount, 2) }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $sold_product->cost ? number_format($sold_product->amount - ($sold_product->cost / 1.05  * $sold_product->quantity),2) : 'N/D' }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: We need to see the code

Comment: code! code! code! code! (:

Comment: @num8er there is the code

Comment: @FelippeDuarte there you have the code

Comment: @asolenzal ok, code seems to be ok, but how You pass that array to view? do You make any intermediate operation on resulting array?

Comment: @num8er Nope, I only show the data stored on the array.

Comment: And where is the controller code?

Comment: @num8er The funny thing is that the object that looses data is also on other position of the array and it contains data :)

Comment: @FelippeDuarte the controller just pass the returned results to the view

Comment: please replace `@foreach` with `<?php foreach($product_sales as $sold_product) : var_dump($sold_product); die; ?>` and show us result.

Comment: @asolenzal try to extend php's memory limit and try again

Comment: @num8er var dump returns the same stuff and my php memory limit is 1G and the object printed is very small

Comment: how about to pass to view this array: `['product_sales' => [$product_sales[sizeof($product_sales)-1] ]`  - I mean to pass to view an array with last object in array.

Comment: `return $results;` is not what you are using to return your view ... It would dump JSON to the browser.  Is the JSON truncated the same way?  What is the real controller code used with the view code you have included?